# jQuery: change selectable dropdown options based on radio button selection

Tags: jquery

I have a php web form, when user selects a radio button, I want only certain options to be available in the dropdown.  So for example, if I select **House** from my radio group, I only want the user to see the **House1**, **House2** and **House 3** options in the dropdown.

Is that possible using jquery?   If so, how would i code this?

**jsFiddle here:** http://jsfiddle.net/justmelat/kkk7J/

**html here:**

```
<form method="post">
    <fieldset id="Group1" name="Group1">
    <legend>Group box</legend>
    <input id="Radio1" name="Radio1" type="radio" value="House" />House<br />
    <input id="Radio1" name="Radio1" type="radio" value="Condo" />Condo<br />
<input id="Radio1" name="Radio1" type="radio" value="Boat" />Boat<br />
    </fieldset><br/><br/>

    <fieldset id="Group2" name="Group2">
    <legend>Group Options</legend>
    <select id="Select1" name="Select1">
    <option value="HO-House 1">House 1</option>
    <option value="HO-House 2">House 2</option>
    <option value="HO-House 3">House 3</option>
    <option value="CO-Condo 1">Condo 1</option>
    <option value="CO-Condo 2">Condo 2</option>
    <option value="CO-Condo 3">Condo 3</option>
    <option value="BO-Boat 1">Boat 1</option>
    <option value="BO-Boat 2">Boat 2</option>
    <option value="BO-Boat 3">Boat 3</option>

    </select></fieldset></form>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I've come across this before and it is possible to achieve in what you're trying to do. It is PHP that I did. I can't give you the full scripts as I don't have a ready archive to check against. I got some clue by studying this www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp to get the answers you're looking for. I think it might be PHP Sessions. It is not hard as you think. Some people might choose a different approach instead of PHP?.

Comment: Will you already have all the information saved or will you have to make an ajax call do get the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could look like this:

```
$(function(){

    var select = $('#Select1'),
        options = select.find('option');

    $('[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        var visibleItems = options.filter('[value*="' + $(this).val()  + '"]').show();
        options.not(visibleItems).hide();

        if(visibleItems.length > 0)
        {
            select.val(visibleItems.eq(0).val());
        }
    });
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kkk7J/2/

Comment: Webdeveloper - this is amazing - I am testing because I think I need to be able to - let me test because something is a little fuzzy to me. back shortly.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way is just assign css classes to the select options and show/hide them.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9Tbpq/

```
<form method="post">
    <fieldset id="Group1" name="Group1">
        <legend>Group box</legend>
        <input id="Radio1" name="Radio1" type="radio" value="House" />House<br />
        <input id="Radio1" name="Radio1" type="radio" value="Condo" />Condo<br />
        <input id="Radio1" name="Radio1" type="radio" value="Boat" />Boat<br />
    </fieldset>
    <br/><br/>

    <fieldset id="Group2" name="Group2">
        <legend>Group Options</legend>
        <select id="Select1" name="Select1">
            <option>Select</option>
            <option value="HO-House 1">House 1</option>
            <option value="HO-House 2">House 2</option>
            <option value="HO-House 3">House 3</option>
            <option value="CO-Condo 1">Condo 1</option>
            <option value="CO-Condo 2">Condo 2</option>
            <option value="CO-Condo 3">Condo 3</option>
            <option value="BO-Boat 1">Boat 1</option>
            <option value="BO-Boat 2">Boat 2</option>
            <option value="BO-Boat 3">Boat 3</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
</form>​
```

.

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    $('input:radio').change(function(){
        var val = $('input:radio:checked').val();
        console.log(val)
        $('#Select1').val(0)
        $('option[value]').hide();
        $('option[value*="-' + val + '"]').show();
    });
});​
</script>
```

Comment: WOW OneOfOne, this is like 99.5% of what I want. This is an auto-generating form.  I may not be able to add the class in as you suggest.  I will check - but can jquery check the values in the select and see if it contains, in this example 'HO-' and only show those values or 'BO-' and show only those values?

Comment: `$('option[value*="HO-"' + val + ']').show();`, however you have to make sure "val" is captalized exactly how it is set for the option's value.

Answer (score 2):

You have two elements with an `id` of "Radio1."  You should probably change that.

Code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/kkk7J/5/

```
//record of temporarily removed  options
var oldoptions = [];

$("[type=radio]").on('click', function () {
   //add all filtered options back
   $("#Select1").append(oldoptions);

   //Remove any option whose text does not contain the text of the selected
   //radio button
   oldoptions = $("#Select1 option:not(:contains(" + $(this).val() + "))").detach();
});​
```

Detaching the elements is necessary because not all browsers support hiding `<option>`.  Additionally, at least some browsers will keep the currently selected option even if it becomes hidden.  These are both solved easily by detaching.

Comment: Explosion Pills - this is very, actually extremely helpful because I know the clients that use this web form all have different browsers.  For their circumstance and using your solution, how can it be altered so that it checks the values in the dropdown for specific chars, example if House selected from radios, look in dropdown, show only the values that contain 'HO-'?  Is that possible?

Comment: @user1176783 the easiest way to do that would be to put some value in the radio buttons themselves like `<input type="radio" value="House" data-match="HO-">` .. then instead of using `$(this).val()` in my code you would use `$(this).data('match')`.