# Change contents in dropdown using javascript

Tags: javascript

Think I'm making this harder than it need to be.  here is my jsfiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/justmelat/pArU7/2/`

**straight html:**

```
<form>
.
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="House">House&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Cars">Cars
    <hr>
        <select name="cars">
            <option value="0">--Select--</option>
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
<option value="wood">Wood</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
<option value="brick">Brick</option>

</select>
</form>
```

when user selects **house**, i only want the **select**, **wood** and **brick** options to appear in the dropdown
of course if cars is selected then **wood** and **brick** should **disappear**.

How can I easily do this in javascript?

Comment: Check below link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765483/jquery-change-selectable-dropdown-options-based-on-radio-button-selection

Answer (score 2):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/33tJR/

Just a quick mockup I made, nothing too fancy using jQuery or anything

```
function createOption(value) {
    el = document.createElement('option');
    el.value = value;
    el.innerHTML = value;
    el.id = value;

    document.getElementById('select').appendChild(el);
}

document.getElementById('house').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('select').innerHTML = '';

    createOption('Volvo');
    createOption('Saab');
    createOption('Fiat');
});

document.getElementById('cars').addEventListener('click', function() {
      document.getElementById('select').innerHTML = '';

    createOption('Wood');
    createOption('Brick')
});
```

Comment: Upvoted, for being the only answer that doesn't use jQuery. I know jQuery lends itself well to the solution, but I don't believe in providing only jQuery to a question that doesn't specify or ask for it.

Comment: I believe than asking the question should be better :) and specific

Comment: In the question i asked "How can I easily do this in javascript?"

Answer (score -2):

Use the onchange event of radio button and if the value matches to male , call a javascript which will create the option list and clear the exisiting list and append the new one. All these used jquery

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[name='sex']").change(function() {
       if($(this).value === "male") { loadDLLWithOption1();  }
       else { loadDLLWithOption2(); }
    }
   });
   function loadDLLWithOption1()
    {
         var optionList = '<option>option1</option><option>option2</option>';
         $("#cars").html(optionList); 
    }
```