# If label active, drop-down menu option changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to do it, so if select All country show City0-4, if Country1 - City0-2, Country2 - City3-4 and etc. 
https://jsfiddle.net/yza0ky3o/

```
<div class="search-type">
  <label class="active"><input class="first-tab" name="tab" checked="checked" type="radio">All country</label>
  <label><input name="tab" type="radio">Country1</label>
  <label><input name="tab" type="radio">Country2</label>
  <div class="search-type-arrow"></div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
<select data-placeholder="All city" class="chosen-select-no-single" >
    <option>City0</option>  
    <option>City1</option>
    <option>City2</option>
    <option>City3</option>
    <option>City4</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is not very clear. Try explainig more to avoid downvotes.

Comment: I have a list of cities, by default the first label is selected and all cities in the drop-down menu show.I want  when choosing the second label(it becomes active) in the drop-down menu there were only certain cities (City1 CIty3 CIty4 for example.)

Comment: are you able to use jQuery? if so, take a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765483/jquery-change-selectable-dropdown-options-based-on-radio-button-selection

Comment: yes, thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: change selectable dropdown options based on radio button selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765483/jquery-change-selectable-dropdown-options-based-on-radio-button-selection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick solution using no jQuery - though you can probably save a lot of lines of code using jQuery.

```js
function toggleCities(radio) {
  var select = document.getElementById('cities');
  // loop through cities' options and toggle each one depending on
  // the current radio's value
  for (i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
    var option = select.options[i]
    // add .hide class if radio's value is not all and value is not equal to current country
    option.classList.toggle('hide', radio.value != 'all' && radio.value != option.dataset.country);
  }
}
```

```css
/* create a class to hide option */
option.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-type">
  <!-- add onchange and value attributes to your radios -->
  <label class="active"><input class="first-tab" name="tab" checked="checked" type="radio" onchange="toggleCities(this)" value="all">All country</label>
  <label><input name="tab" type="radio" onchange="toggleCities(this)" value="1">Country1</label>
  <label><input name="tab" type="radio" onchange="toggleCities(this)" value="2">Country2</label>
  <div class="search-type-arrow"></div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <!-- add ID attribute to your select -->
  <select id="cities" data-placeholder="All city" class="chosen-select-no-single">
    <!-- add data-attribute to your options -->
    <option data-country="1">City0</option>  
    <option data-country="1">City1</option>
    <option data-country="1">City2</option>
    <option data-country="2">City3</option>
    <option data-country="2">City4</option>
</select>
</div>
```

- [HTML onchange Event Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onchange.asp)
- [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)
- [Using data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

**Edit: jQuery solution**

```js
$(function () {
  // attach onchange event to radio buttons
  $('input[name=tab]').change(function () {
    var radio = this;
    // loop through each option
    $('#cities option').each(function () {
      // show option if radio's value is ALL or equal to option's country
      $(this).toggle(radio.value == 'all' || radio.value == this.dataset.country);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search-type">
  <!-- add value attributes to your radios -->
  <label class="active"><input class="first-tab" name="tab" checked="checked" type="radio" value="all">All country</label>
  <label><input name="tab" type="radio" value="1">Country1</label>
  <label><input name="tab" type="radio" value="2">Country2</label>
  <div class="search-type-arrow"></div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <!-- add ID attribute to your select -->
  <select id="cities" data-placeholder="All city" class="chosen-select-no-single">
    <!-- add data-attribute to your options -->
    <option data-country="1">City0</option>  
    <option data-country="1">City1</option>
    <option data-country="1">City2</option>
    <option data-country="2">City3</option>
    <option data-country="2">City4</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: could you write jQuery solution?