# How to change combo box in radio button cheked use ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

How do I change the value combo box based on the checked radio button?
I use AJAX to change it, I use this code to change the value combo box with the combo box I used successfully.
But, when I use a radio button with a combo box it doesn't work.
What is wrong?

This JQuery i use JQuery Boostrap.

```js
$(function(){

$.ajaxSetup({
type:"POST",
url: "<?php echo base_url('index.php/select/ambil_data') ?>",
cache: false,
});

var var_name = $("input[id='j_kI)]:checked").val();
if(var_name)
    var value=$(this).val();
    if(value>0){
        $.ajax({
            data:{modul:'kamar_ikhwan'},
            success: function(respond){
                $("#kamar").html(respond);
            }
        })
    }
});

$("input:radio[id=j_kI] :selected").val(function(){
    var value=$(this).val();
    if(value>0){
        $.ajax({
            data:{modul:'kamar_akhwat'},
            success: function(respond){
                $("#kamar").html(respond);
            }
        })
    }
});

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php echo form_open_multipart($action,'method="post" id="demo-form2" data-parsley-validate="" class="form-horizontal form-label-left" novalidate=""')  ?>
          
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Jenis kelamin <?php echo form_error('j_k')?></label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <?php
                                if($j_k=="L"){
                                    echo "Laki-laki <input type='radio' name='j_k' id='j_kI' value='L' checked onclick='javascript:yesnoCheck();' />"." ".
                                    "Perempuan <input type='radio'  name='j_k' id='j_kA' value='P' onclick='javascript:yesnoCheck();' />";
                                }
                                elseif($j_k=="P"){
                                    echo "Laki-laki <input type='radio'  name='j_k' id='j_kI' value='L' onclick='javascript:yesnoCheck();' />"." ".
                                    "Perempuan <input type='radio' name='j_k' id='j_kA' value='P' checked onclick='javascript:yesnoCheck();' />";
                                }
                                elseif(empty($j_k)==TRUE || $j_k==""){
                                    echo "Laki-laki <input type='radio'  name='j_k' id='j_kI' value='L' />"." ".
                                    "Perempuan <input type='radio'  name='j_k' id='j_kA' value='P'  />";
                                }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="varchar">Kamar <?php// echo form_error('kamar') ?></label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <select class="form-control" id="kamar" name="kamar">
                                <option value=""></option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        <div class="ln_solid"></div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" /> 
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i> <?php echo $button ?></button> 
     <a href="<?php echo site_url('super_admin/mhs_list') ?>" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-reply-all"></i> Cancel</a>
 </div>
                    </div></form>
```

### This Controller

```
function ambil_data(){

    $modul=$this->input->post('modul');
    $id=$this->input->post('id');

    //kamar
    if($modul=="kamar_ikhwan"){
        echo $this->model_select->kamar_ikhwan();
    }
    elseif($modul=="kamar_akhwat"){
        echo $this->model_select->kamar_akhwat();
    }

}
```

### This Model

```
function kamar_akhwat(){
    $kamar="<option value='0'>--pilih--</pilih>";

    $this->db->order_by('kamar','ASC');
    $jur= $this->db->get('kamar_akhwat');

    foreach ($jur->result_array() as $data ){
        $kamar.= "<option value='$data[id]'>$data[kamar]</option>";
    }
return $kamar;
}
function kamar_ikhwan(){
    $kamar="<option value='0'>--pilih--</pilih>";

    $this->db->order_by('kamar','ASC');
    $jur= $this->db->get('kamar_ikhwan');
    foreach ($jur->result_array() as $data ){
        $kamar.= "<option value='$data[id]'>$data[kamar]</option>";
    }
return $kamar;
}
```

Comment: try using [jquery .on() event](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: based on your question, are you trying create auto populate when the radio button checked, you can following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765483/jquery-change-selectable-dropdown-options-based-on-radio-button-selection)

Comment: `$('[id="j_kI"]').click(function(){
var value=$(this).val();
    //if(value>0){
        $.ajax({
            data:{modul:'kamar_ikhwan'},
            success: function(respond){
                $("#kamar").html(respond);
            }
        })
    //}

});`

Comment: senang bisa membantu